# Spring - internationalized messages inside placeholder

Tags: spring, jsp, internationalization

Is it possible to make internationalized messages inside placeholder element ?

```
<form:input path="year" type="number" id="inputYear" pattern="[0-9]"
            placeholder='<spring:message code="Test.Create.PHYear"/>'/>
<form:errors path="year" cssClass="error"></form:errors>
```

My placeholder escape HTML tags and return exactly what I typed "spring:message..." instead of value that it should represents

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy a message to some variable

```
<spring:message code="Test.Create.PHYear" var="msg"/>
```

then use it in EL

```
<form:input path="year" type="number" id="inputYear" pattern="[0-9]"
            placeholder="${msg}"/>
<form:errors path="year" cssClass="error"></form:errors>
```